# Tag synonyms - Info Page

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

The `arrays` tag info page says that `array` will be remapped to `arrays`, but `array` says nothing. Shouldn't there be a notice that it will be remapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you propose we show there?

Keep in mind, arrays and array *should* be merged. There is absolutely no reason to have  stuff tagged with the old synonym once a synonym is in place.

Nobody will be navigating to a question filter without questions in it.

Comment: It should say that it is being merged until the process is complete